# X-Accel-Redirect not working with SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, nginx, x-accel-redirect

I am using the `X-Accel-redirect` feature of Nginx for playing videos with a php file named video2.php with the following code:

```
header("X-Accel-Redirect: /Restr/" . $file);
```

(of course, much more executable code before, not necessary by now)

I also have the following file, pla.php, with 2 players embedded:
First player as  `source src="http://example.com/video2.php" type="video/mp4"`, The second as source `src="video2.php" type="video/mp4"`

First player works and second doesn't when I am in https mode.
Both players work when I am in http mode. The first player plays in https because the full link in http.

That means Nginx works fine with SSL in all cases but one. `X-Accel-redirect` feature is not working when the domain is set to https. It works perfectly in http mode.

The `nginx.conf` is

```
user nobody;

worker_processes auto;


error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
events 
{
worker_connections 1024; 

use epoll; 

}

http 
{

open_file_cache max=5000 inactive=30s;

open_file_cache_valid 120s;
open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
open_file_cache_errors off;
open_log_file_cache max=1024 inactive=30s min_uses=2;
server_names_hash_max_size 10240;
server_names_hash_bucket_size 1024;
include mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 5;
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_min_length 1000;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_types text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/xml image/png image/x-icon image/gif image/jpeg application/xml+rss text/javascript application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json;
ignore_invalid_headers on;
client_header_timeout 3m;
client_body_timeout 3m;
client_max_body_size 200m;
send_timeout 3m;
connection_pool_size 256;
client_header_buffer_size 4k;
large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
request_pool_size 4k;
output_buffers 4 32k;
postpone_output 1460;
proxy_temp_path /tmp/nginx_temp;
log_format bytes_log "$msec $bytes_sent .";

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

In `xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.conf`

```
server {
listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:82;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.xxx.xxx.xxx.xx.log;
server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xx;
root /usr/local/apache/htdocs;
location / {
location ~.*\.(3gp|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|wmv|avi|asf|asx|mpg|mpeg|mp4|pls|mp3|mid|wav|swf|flv|html|htm|txt|js|css|exe|zip|tar|rar|gz|tgz|bz2|uha|7z|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|iso|woff|ttf|svg|eot)\$ {
expires 7d; #Comment this out if you are using the apache backend cache-control/expires headers.
try_files \$uri \@backend;
}
error_page 405 = \@backend;
error_page 500 = \@custom;
add_header X-Cache "HIT from Backend";
proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8181;
include proxy.inc;
}
location \@backend {
internal;
proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8181;
include proxy.inc;
}
location \@custom {
internal;
proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8181;
include proxy.inc;
}
location ~ .*\.(php|jsp|cgi|pl|py)?\$ {
proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8181;
include proxy.inc;
}
location ~ /\.ht {
deny all;
}
}
```

It seems here is the key, all is set to http only, not https.

the code of `proxy.inc` below from etc/nginx/

```
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_connect_timeout 59s;
proxy_send_timeout 600;
proxy_read_timeout 600;
proxy_buffer_size 64k;
proxy_buffers 16 32k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_hide_header Vary;
proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding '';
#If you want to get the cache-control and expire headers from apache, comment out 'proxy_ignore_headers' and uncomment 'proxy_pass_header Expires;' and 'proxy_pass_header Cache-Control
#proxy_pass_header Expires;
#proxy_pass_header Cache-Control;
proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;
proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Any help will be apreciated